# problem with border-width attribute

Tags: css

In the example .html file below, the border-width attribute does not appear to be doing anything in either firefox 5 or firefox 3.6.18.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;" />
<style type="text/css">
  a:link img { 
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p><a href="alexander-cb.html"><img src="thumbs/thumb-avh.jpg" alt="CB" /></a> A court barony.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I have tried 1px, 3px, and 5px, and this does not change the output.  Why is the border-width property being ignored?

Comment: tried using shorthand? (`border:1px solid blue`)

Comment: It [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/u5dcM/), in Firefox 5 (Ubuntu 11.04). Have you got a more specific rule somewhere (specifying more of the element's ancestors, using any `id`-based selectors) that's over-riding this one?

Comment: It is also working for me in FireFox 5. I agree with @david in suspecting you might have a more specific rule elsewhere overriding this one. Maybe post more of the code if you cannot see the issue yourself. Or provide a link to the full site/jsfiddle.

Comment: The issue happens with the complete example that I posted; there is no external CSS that is being called.  (The two versions of firefox that I tested this on are on two different machines).

Answer (score 0):

Are you forgetting to give it a border-color? It defaults to transparent if it isn't explicitly set.

Comment: Adding a border-color doesn't appear to make any difference; with or without that attribute specified, the border *does* show up, but changing the border-width does nothing.  (I currently have a version of the above code with `border-width: 20px;` and `border-color: #0000CC;`, and the border, while present, is definitely not 20px, and it is the same as in the version where I don't have the border-color specified.  The example is at http://www.ellipsis.cx/~liana/candi/example.html.)